# SEO Friendly URLs & .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to make my URLs SEO friendly but am having issues with my .htaccess

This is how my URL currently looks:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dns/?domain=stackoverflow.com&submit=Report
```

But I want it to show like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/dns/stackoverflow.com
```

I've tried so many things I don't know if it's even possible to do so I just wanted to start over with guidance from you guys.  The .htaccess I'm working with is in the /dns/ folder.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: change all of your links and anchors in all of your pages to look like this: `http://www.mysite.com/dns/stackoverflow.com`, so when someone clicks a link on your site, they go to a link that looks like `http://www.mysite.com/dns/stackoverflow.com` instead of `http://www.mysite.com/dns/?domain=stackoverflow.com&submit=Report`

**Step 2**: In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules (above any rules that you may already have):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?dns/(.+)$ /dns/?domain=$1&submit=Report [L,QSA]
```

**Step 3**: In the event that a GET method form submission is generating the link, you can add these rules too:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /dns/\?domain=([^&\ ]+)(&submit=Report)?
RewriteRule ^/?dns/?$ /dns/%2? [L,R=301]
```